# Sine wave trajectory in MatLab

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

I was wondering if there was a way to write a function to calculate the trajectory of a sine wave in MATLAB? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is "the trajectory of a sine wave"?

Comment: The function accepts time values in a vector and then gives the trajectory of the sine wave

Comment: But what is the trajectory of the sine wave? How is it defined?

Comment: Are you talking about the slope at any point on a sine curve? Or the direction of a traveling wave? Or something else? Sounds like a math/physics question instead of a programming/syntax question.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same ambiguous question in my MATLAB homework (maybe we're in the same class?).  It's very unclear what the question is asking so I had trouble figuring it out too.  I ended up trying random sine operations and soon found that the trajectory of the sine wave (T) over time (t) is as follows:

```
 T = sin(t)
```

As simple as this answer is, I'm not entirely sure why it is correct.  I don't usually like giving straight answers but in this case the question is so ambiguous that OP probably wouldn't be able to find the solution without resorting to random guessing like I did.